# Why React renders my component a second time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following ReactJS code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default function App() {
    console.log('Render');

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleOpen = () => {
        setIsOpen(true);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleOpen}>Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When the app loads in the browser "Render" is outputted in the console.
Then, when I click on the button, "Render" is outputted another time, and it makes sense because the state changes.

However, another click on the button, outputs "Render" again in the console :/
And after that when clicking on the button, no more outputs.

Can someone help me understand why this component is rendered on the second button click?

Thanks

Comment: After the first click the value in state doesn't actually change from it's previous value so react doesn't need to do any new rendering. Try changing to `setIsOpen(!isOpen);` instead and you will see the log each time